# Google Sheets into Big Query Data Size

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does integrating Google Sheets with BigQuery incurs higher data storage fees? For example if I have to save a csv file on Sheets and then export it to BigQuery will the file size be bigger compared to having a csv file stored on Google Cloud?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#overview_of_pricing), there isn't any charge for integrating Google Sheets with  BigQuery. In BigQuery, you are charged for storage and query processing. Furthermore, I don't see any reason for the same file in Google Sheets and GCS to have different size, if it is the same file. Then, it will have the same size. Did this information answer your question?